# Rails4 - Edit parameters of an Object before remotely saving it in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

Beginner with some dev experience here.

I have an app with multiple models and I have managed to work everything out but i am stuck here.

I have a model, called CartEntries

```
    class CartEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_paranoid
    belongs_to :cart
    belongs_to :sign
```

With a create method in the Cart Entry controller

```
    def create
    @entry = @cart.entries.create(entry_params)
    if @entry.save
        flash[:notice] = translate 'flash.notice'
    else
        flash[:error] = translate 'flash.error'
    end
    support_ajax_flashes!
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html # renders view
        format.json { render json: @entry }
    end
end
```

And a Model Sign with static signs inputed in the database and no create method.

```
    class Sign < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :cart_entries
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :cart_entries
```

And from a Sign's view I initialize a new instance of a CartEntry and succsessfuly create a new Cart Entry after clicking the link, generating a notification.

```
    <% @entry = CartEntry.new(sign: @sign)%>
    <%= link_to t('.add_to_cart'), user_cart_entries_path(:entry => @entry.attributes),method: :post, remote: true, "data-type" => :json%>
```

The Cart Entry has another field called **Count** with a default value of 1. **Im looking for a way for the user to input this number in a text field and when creating the Cart Entry , pass the Count the user inputed instead of the default 1.** 
What ever I try passes the default value. 
While

```
   <% @entry = CartEntry.new(sign: @sign, count: 5)%>
```

Does the trick properly, and passes 5 as the value , but I want the user to input this number since its clearly a variable.

While I understand that

```
    <% @entry = CartEntry.new(sign: @sign)%>
```

Initializes the entry object on page load and that i must move it, I'm asking you kind people, where?

**UPDATE**

Entry Params:

```
    private

    def entry_params
      params.require(:entry).permit(:sign_id, :count)
    end
```

Comment: please add the implementation of the `entry_params` method

Answer (score 1):

Answering in reverse order from your question:

1. Initializing the new CartEntry object should probably be in the `new` action of your controller. Rails controllers often have both `new` and `create`, `new` being tied to rendering the form to receive input and `create` being the action tied to the 'Submit' button. Your `new` action is often just something like:

   ```
   def new
     @entry = CartEntry.new(sign: @sign)
   end
   ```

   Your view to prompt the user for data should be named new.html.erb and have the form in it.
2. For getting the data from the form to your create method, you are half way there I think. If you moved the example you gave:

   ```
   <% @entry = CartEntry.new(sign: @sign, count: 5)%>
   ```

   to the `create` action in the controller, it would be

   ```
    @entry = CartEntry.new(sign: @sign, count: params[:count])
    @entry.save
   ```

   Remember 'params' is just a hash that contains the form input data.

Hope that helps!